# "MyVar" is not definedPylancereportUndefinedVariable

Tags: python, django

- **goal**: I am trying to create I, reusable class, for Django and I created a variable called `MyVar` inside it in order to overwrite it later when I re-use this class `ItemsView`.
- **Problem**: when i use `MyVar` inside MySerializer it says `"MyVar" is not definde`

```
class ItemsView(OtherClass):
    MyVar = 'any ...'

    class MySerializer(OneMoreClasse):
        class Meta:
            model = MyVar
            fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: You can not do this. The subclass has a specific context. Furthermore even if that was possible, then inheriting it will not change the `MySerializer`, since that class is constructed at the `ItemsView` class level, not that of any subclass.

Comment: see this despite the original class had other value I was able to overwrite them https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zbLnbC4cJXBhAzzkQRnjTLNqNuPsG2lT#scrollTo=aaPPy7OtED6w

Comment: @alialkaraawi: you can override a variable, but that will not have any impact on the `MySerializer`, since that one is created when you create the `ItemsView`, not when you create *subclasses* of the `ItemsView`.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments it is probably better to find a different way to structure what you are trying to do. But if you are for some reason tied to this structure, you could access it during inner class instantiation:

```
class Outer():
    MyVar = 'abc'
    
    class Inner():
        def __init__(self):
            self.MyInnerVar = Outer.MyVar
```

But the value of MyVar will only be passed during instantiation. Try this:

```
my_outer = Outer()
print(my_outer.MyVar)
my_inner = my_outer.Inner()
print(my_inner.MyInnerVar)
my_outer = 'def'
print(my_inner.MyInnerVar)
```

and the last line will print 'abc', not 'def'.